# Custom web form in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can I make custom web form with my controls and other properties in asp.net?
because I am searching about this issue and can't find any thing

Comment: what you mean by your controls ?

Comment: Every page you make in ASP.NET is a custom web form.. what do you mean?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: I mean that how to make custom web form with specific controls and then this form appeared in visual studio installed templates so that i can use it in my application instead of making this form many thimes

Comment: what you are looking for is UserControl/Custom Control basically.

Comment: Do you mean that I can't make custom web form?
only make custom UserControl?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for custom controls not custom form/custom control check [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28783/Your-First-ASP-NET-Custom-Control) and [this](http://webproject.scottgu.com/CSharp/UserControls/UserControls.aspx). Choosing one of custom control and user control would depend on certain scenarios analyse you need and you can choose one of them.

If you want to roll out your own template [this](http://blog.reybango.com/2010/09/21/how-to-create-html5-website-and-page-templates-for-visual-studio-2010/) may be of help to you.

Comment: I made custom controls and know it but I am asking about the ability to make custom web form?

Comment: every page you have made is custom web form, if you are talking about ability to be visible in toolbox Custom Control is what you need,

Comment: I need this page(custom form) to be visible in visual studio templates so that i can use it in any other application

Answer (score 0):

You can use Custom Controls and WebUserControls in your form not Custom form.

Please refer this.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_custom_controls.htm

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa728786(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here's a really old guide how to do it, it seems to be rare enough that it's kind of hard to find up to date information on how this is done:

http://sellsbrothers.com/writing/projectItemTemplates.htm

Comment: I admired with the title and the first image in the page but when i read the topic I didn't understand anything